# How to create jquery Auto Complete in Popup window

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I am using this code for creating auto complete

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    function log( message )
    {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
    $( "#group" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source: "ajax.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui )
        {
            $("#log").append("<div>"+ui.item.value+" </div>");
        }
    });

});
function clearFld()
{
    document.getElementById('group').value = "";
}
</script>
```

This is working fine after page loads.How i can get this same behavior on popup

Comment: Have you tried something? When you have code that fails, you will probably be in a better position to ask a more specific question :)